# To display mat-menu items below the mat-menu button

Tags: css, angular-material

I am using `Menu with icons` component.Here on clicking the button(i,e menu).The menu items(i,e mat-menu items) are displaying above the button as shown in below image.

[image]

I want the items(ex logout) to be displayed below the menu button.I tried giving **margin** and **padding** properties still no result.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-ofah6f?file=app/header/header.component.html) link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want to prevent the overlapping the trigger of the menu itself, the `mat-menu` has a custom attribute just for this. It is called `overlapTrigger` and if you set it to `false`, the menu-item won't overlap your trigger (the account icon). See example code below:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
   <button mat-menu-item>
       <mat-icon>power_settings_new</mat-icon>
       <span>Logout</span>
   </button>
</mat-menu>
```

Full example at [forked stackblitz](https://angular-material-icon-7zqmku.stackblitz.io/)

You can read more about it right [here](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#customizing-menu-position).